# How can I create an empty list in the variable table to use it in keywords table?

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I am trying to create an empty list in the variable table to use it in some keywords, but it doesn't work.

This is my MWE

```
*** Settings ***
Library    BuiltIn
Library    Collections

*** Variables ***
${mylist} =    Create List

*** Test Cases ***
First Test Case
    Populate list

*** Keywords ***
Populate list
    Append To List    ${mylist}    foo    bar
```

and this is the error

```
TypeError: Expected argument 1 to be a list or list-like, got string instead.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't call keywords in the `Variables` section.. ALso, you say you are trying to create an empty list but then you are trying to treat it as a dictionary. Which is it supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when creating the post, I really wanted to say Append To List...So the solution is to define the list as follows `${mylist}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call keywords in the `Variables` section. What you've done is to define `${mylist}` to be the string "Create List".

If you want to declare an empty list in the variables section, use the `@` so robot knows you're creating a list:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    BuiltIn
Library    Collections

*** Variables ***
@{mylist}

*** Test Cases ***
First Test Case
    Populate list
    List should contain value  ${mylist}  foo
    List should contain value  ${mylist}  bar

*** Keywords ***
Populate list
    Append to list       ${mylist}    foo    bar
```